# How to restore nginx.conf

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I accidentally remove nginx.conf.  I'm afraid to restart nginx now.
nginx now is taking its configuration from a location that I don't know.
can I restore it? from cache or something like that?
My server is ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

You can try to dump the config file if nginx is still running by using the -T flag

`nginx -T` or

`/usr/sbin/nginx -T`

Otherwise try following those answers:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599996/restore-deleted-version-of-nginx-configuration

https://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process

Comment: the  nginx is not yet restarted but how this command can restore it?

Comment: Nginx is able to change the configuration on the fly. The -T parameter checks the configuration file and dumps it. If you dont provide a configuration file it should dump the current file. But read up on it [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/) and [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html) and read the answers of the questions I provided above.

Comment: nginx -T read the current configuration /etc/nginx/nginx.conf which is removed

Comment: So it didn't work or you didn't try? I don't know of any solution other than those stated in the linked questions.

Comment: Yes it didn't work,
No problem i have found some backup  
thank you